# show that there is a set $ A \ $ with positive measure such that $ \ T(A) \cap A= \phi $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ T $ be an **Ergodic** invertible finite -measure preserving transformation  transformation on a canonical measure space $ (X,S, \lambda) \ $ . show that there is a set $ A \ $ with positive measure such that $ \ T(A) \cap A= \phi $.

**Answer:**

Let $ A=[a,b) \ $ and $ T(x)=a+c , \ \ s.t. \ \ c>b \ $ ,

Then $ \lambda (A)=b-a >0 \ $ but $ T(A) \cap A=[a+c, b+c)\cap [a,b) =\phi \ $

**Am I right ?  If not then how to find $ A $ ?**

Help me

Comment: Do you mean $\phi$ or $\emptyset$?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is just an example (also your $T$ is not ergodic/missing some context of your space).

In general choose your favourite $A$ with positive measure s.t. $X\setminus A$ has also positive measure.
Since $T$ is ergodic, the $T^n(A) \ $  (for $n \in \mathbb Z)$ cover $X$ (up to some null-set) that shows that $T(A)\setminus A$ has not zero-measure. Take the preimage of this set and you are done :-)